# read matrix from txt file and save to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, file, matrix

I use the code below to read a matrix from a file and it works well but now I need to split the rows and columns by spaces to become a matrix in order to use it in another function. Unfortunately I do not know how I can deal with ArrayList, So can anyone help me to edit this code??

```
private  static void read(Matrix matrix) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    String line = null;
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\TDarray.txt"));
    while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) { 
        list.add(getArray(line));
    }        
    reader.close();

    for (String[] stringArr : list) {
        for(String str : stringArr){
            System.out.print(str+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

private static String[] getArray(String s){
    String[] array = s.split("\\s");
    return array;
}
```

and this is the sample of my text file:

```
3.2  4.7
0.4  0.5  0.6  0.1  0.7
0.1  0.8  0.4
0.1  0.3  0.4  0.9  1.0
0.2  0.9  0.6  0.7  0.2
```

Comment: What *deal with ArrayList* means exactly?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: What is the current structure of the matrix in your `.txt` file. Please post a sample of the current text file

Comment: @FreshD I just edit my post and I post a sample of the text file

Comment: And as result you want to have the matrix split with blanks in what. Do you want to write them back to a file or should they be stored in a String

Comment: What is the class Matrix ?

Comment: @FreshD I need results to be save in matrix because I need it to compare with another one, So I need to split by spaces for rows and blank for columns

Comment: space and blank is the same. But if you are talking about new line this is done by `\n`

Comment: @FreshD Yes I mean new line , I'm really sorry for my english. Is the code enough or I need to edit more?

Answer (score 0):

To split the columns by newline just add `\n`. For your print output you can also use this. Now instead of printing you can fill your matrix with this.

```
for (String[] stringArr : list) {
    for(String str : stringArr){
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code.
If you need to use a Matrix for mathematical calculation in later stage there's no point in storing it as `List<String[]>`

```
private static Vector<Vector<Float>> loadMatrixAsVector() throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "D:\\test.txt"));
    Vector<Vector<Float>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<Float>>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Vector<Float> rowVector = new Vector<Float>();
        for (String value : line.split(" ")) {
            rowVector.add(Float.valueOf(value));
        }
        matrix.add(rowVector);
    }
    reader.close();

    System.out.println("Matrix : " + matrix);
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I recall this function in the main? I did not use it before.

Comment: How do you call System.out.println ?
Go learn basic Java first. We're not here to teach you well documented java Syntax. If you need some help in some specific problems, first post your current code/pseudo-code stating you problem and requirement.
Calling a static method Methods from main is the very basic part of Java Syntax

Comment: After calling this method you'll have an Object of 2D Vector Containing Float values. Then you are free to do anything with that Object

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know how to call the function, but the function you gave it is new for me so for first time I do not how to recall it but after that I did it and work very well. again thank you

Comment: If that answers your question please mark it as answer. That will help others to identify correct solution if they have similar problems like you.